# Why do we need to approximate values when we can easily come up with the exact value?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Why do we need to approximate values when we can easily come up with the exact value? For instance, finding the max error in the measurement of a cone can easily be computed. Why do we still need to approximate error using differentials? It doesn't make sense..

Comment: What is the decimal expansion for $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers find it much easier to approximate integrals than analytically calculate them. From a practical perspective, you can approximate a differential to as high a degree of accuracy as you want. When doing them manually, not all integrals are easy to find (and some are even impossible).

Comment: ah that make sense. thanks